# Which planet was mentioned at Kobol [spoilers]

Tags: battlestar-galactica

When the humans reach Kobol and enter the tomb of Athena, they realize that Earth is the planet where the 12 constellations and the nebula are visible from. Which Earth was referred to here? Was it the one where the 13th tribe had lived before being nuked? Or was it the one where the fleet ended up at last? (This seems unlikely because no one knew that it existed.)

So which Earth was it?

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, the next planet they found was the one that was nuked, so I think that was Earth referenced in the tomb. Also, I believe that later when they find the new planet, which was discovered spontaneously by Starbuck putting together hints from the piano player and memories from her childhood, there is some debate over whether it should be called Earth, but it was settled based on Adama's opinion that Earth was a place in their hearts.

Comment: but the 12 constellations and the nebula were not visible from the planet where the 13th tribe used to live but they are visible from our current planet earth (which was what they discovered at the end). So it either means that the tomb mentioned our earth or that the writers made a mistake :P

Comment: Or that the writers had a larger story they wanted to tell, and we don't know it. We never learned what Starbuck was. The very end of the show was Gaius Baltar and Caprica 6 alter egos walking and talking in modern-day Earth, and they mention some greater being who prefers not to be called God. Throughout the show we saw the Caprica 6 alter ego pushing the "one true God" more than any other character. Starbuck randomly guesses the location Earth (that can view those constellations). Is this really an example of writers making a mistake?